# Update dataframe based on index and append the new ones

Tags: python, pandas

Df1:

```
Id    val
1     4
3     7
9     2
4     5
```

Df2:

```
Id    val
1     5
7     2
```

Required:

```
Id    val
1     5
3     7
9     2
4     5
7     2
```

I have these df1 and df2 and I want to get the required df where common Ids present in Df1 and Df2 will get updated, and new Ids will get appended.

I dont seem to find if I need to use update, merge or join or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `combine_first`

```
df2.set_index('Id').combine_first(df1.set_index('Id')).reset_index()
Out[6]: 
   Id  val
0   1  5.0
1   3  7.0
2   4  5.0
3   7  2.0
4   9  2.0
```

Comment: Quick question: the appended dataframe will be df2 or df1?

Comment: @star_kid df1 . since you want to update df1 's value from df2 , so df1 is the appended

Answer (score 6):

Use `concat` with `drop_duplicates` (note, order may not be preserved).

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('Id', keep='last')

   Id  val
1   3    7
2   9    2
3   4    5
0   1    5
1   7    2
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `dictionary` unpacking

```
m1 = dict(zip(df1.Id, df1.val))
m2 = dict(zip(df2.Id, df2.val))

pd.DataFrame([*{**m1, **m2}.items()], columns=['Id', 'val'])

   Id  val
0   1    5
1   3    7
2   4    5
3   7    2
4   9    2
```

---

Alternate Form

```
cols = ['Id', 'val']
m1 = dict(zip(*map(df1.get, cols)))
m2 = dict(zip(*map(df2.get, cols)))

pd.DataFrame([*{**m1, **m2}.items()], columns=cols)
```

---

#### `get`

```
m1 = dict(zip(df1.Id, df1.val))
m2 = dict(zip(df2.Id, df2.val))
f = lambda x: m2.get(x, m1.get(x, x))

pd.DataFrame([[x, f(x)] for x in {*df1.Id, *df2.Id}], columns=['Id', 'val'])

   Id  val
0   1    5
1   3    7
2   4    5
3   7    2
4   9    2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can align indices, [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html). The solution is verbose, but maintains row ordering as per your desired result.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Id')
df2 = df2.set_index('Id')

df1.update(df2)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]])\
       .reset_index().astype(int)

print(df)

   Id  val
0   1    5
1   3    7
2   9    2
3   4    5
4   7    2
```